# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Yesterday, I asked this question:

[Could a party other than Ukraine really be shelling the Zhaporizhye NPP?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/could-a-party-other-than-ukraine-really-be-shelling-the-zhaporizhye-npp)

which has gotten a couple of reasonable answers (one of which I upvoted). However, it got 7 downvotes and 3 close votes - and no comments regarding what's supposedly wrong with the question.

So, what *is* wrong with it? The phrasing maybe? Something else?

Comment: Pretty sure that question had comments on it explaining the downvotes, you responded to those comments,  and those comments got deleted.